# How can generate a point using rotation from other point in n-dimensional space?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Suppose we have a point $P_1 = [X_1,X_2, X_3, ... X_n]$ in n-dimension space, How does the rotation of point $P_1$ get another point $P_2= [Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, ...Y_n]$? There is a method to do multiple rotations to form a well-known curve starting from $P_1$, for example [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QnDP.png)

Comment: Are you talking about $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Comment: Yes, where each point has a coordinate in the n axis.

Comment: " There is a *method* to do multiple rotations to form a well-known curve starting from", how is it named?

Comment: Anyway, in the 2 dimensional case you can use complex numbers. For example, powers (positive and negative) of $1 + 0.2i$ give a beautiful spiral around the origin.

Comment: @Elmex80s I ask for that I forgot to make the " ? ". I didn't understand your method of using complex numbers, can you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Powers of complex numbers](http://www.suitcaseofdreams.net/powers_complex.htm) I take these pictures

[image: http://www.suitcaseofdreams.net/Images/TF/spiral4.gif]

and

[image: http://www.suitcaseofdreams.net/Images/TF/spiral5.gif]

which spiral a point around $O$. By taking negative powers you can go other way around as well.

For dimensions higher than 3 I think almost every *invertible* matrix will do.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, I am not a mathematician therefore i have difficulty understanding. So, given one point like in your figure blue ones, how i can find the coordinate of the others points?

Comment: It are all powers of the complex number $z$. $z$ can be every number you want as long $0 < |z| < 1$ or $1 < |z|$. Note in your example the angles increase with every step, in mine their are constant.

Comment: ok good, there is only the version of a complex number? because i want the same things with real numbers. If you have any suggestions please make them as ref or explain them.

Comment: Complex numbers are pairs of real numbers. Lookup how their multiplication works and you should be able to continue. I could write it down but it is searchable everyhwere.

Comment: Ok thank you brother